# Is there a difference in attack speed among one handed weapons?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I was wondering if there is a difference in attack speed between Axes, Swords and Maces. I am not sure if even Daggers have a faster attack speed?

Comment: I note that, I am certain that in Skyrim, there *is* a difference. Not necessarily in ESO though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

I just crafted a Level One Dagger, Sword, Mace, and Axe on my Nightblade. The only thing on him that affects attack speed, is Rank 2 of the [Agility](http://uesp.net/wiki/Online:Agility) passive, giving him +10% attack speed at all times. Between runs, I didn't change anything besides my weapons.

Running one of the weapons with a shield, I consistently timed ten heavy attacks as taking roughly 19.5 seconds. Running any combination of two of the weapons consistently took 18.5 seconds or so. Weapon type had no impact at all.

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is a difference: Considering Attack Speed: Daggers > Swords > Axes > Maces

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back it up?

Comment: That's been on Skyrim and earlier games. In ESO it doesn't matter.